# Https api backend backend in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to separate frontend and backend parts. I deployed frontend to S3 bucket (https) and I have a backend on elasticbeanstalk (with http://***.elasticbeanstalk.com). Since both are development environments I won't buy domain for them and I am looking for a best idea how to make it works together.

HTTPS frontend and HTTP backend doesn't work, because of mixed content
and I can't get HTTPS on *.elasticbeanstalk.com (I would need to have my own domain)

Only idea I see is probably API GATEWAY, but:

1. I am not sure if It would be possible to use HTTPS there
2. I would be hard do deploy changes I think
3. I have quite nice build backend structure and using gateway would ruin that

Maybe some with bigger experience suggest me something?

Comment: Just because they are development environments doesn't mean you shouldn't point your own domain there. You will have to point your own domain there if you want to enable and test HTTPS. If you have a domain name for your production environment like `example.com` then you could point something like `dev.example.com` to your development environment without having to purchase an entirely new domain.

Comment: You can use the default domain name on API Gateway to your backend inside your VPC, then you have the HTTPs endpoint.

Comment: I figured it out, it's possible to turn on https option on elastic beanstalk. So it was possible